# c++ validate input does not work

Tags: c++

I am writing this code below and everything is working fine except when I type multiple characterS it suppose to give invalid input without exit the program but what is happen that  when I wrote multiple characters starting quite 'Q' or 'q' it is exit the program and I do not want that I only want to exit if I type 'q' or 'Q'

```
int main()
{
    char grade;

    while(grade!='Q'&& grade!='q') {

        cout<<"\nEnter one grade Letter from the following"
            <<" (A ,B,C,D or F) or Please or 'q' to quite: ";

        cin>>grade;
        if (cin.get() != '\n') // Look at the next character
            {

                cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); // Clear the input stream

                cout << "\nInvalid input !\n";
            }

        else if (grade != 'A' && grade != 'a'
                 &&  grade != 'B' && grade != 'b'
                 &&  grade != 'C' && grade != 'c'
                 &&  grade != 'D' && grade != 'd'
                 &&  grade != 'F' && grade != 'f'
                 &&  grade != 'Q' && grade != 'q'
                 ) {

            cout << "\nInvalid input !\n";

        }

        else if(grade =='A'||grade=='a')
            cout<<"Excellent"<<endl;
        else if(grade=='B'|| grade=='b')
            cout<<"Good"<<endl;
        else if(grade=='C' || grade=='c')
            cout<<"Fair"<<endl;
        else if (grade=='D' || grade=='d')
            cout<<"Poor"<<endl;
        else if (grade=='F' || grade=='f')
            cout<<"Failure"<<endl;
        //else

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `else if (grade=='Q' || grade=='q')
        break;`

Comment: In the first 3 lines of your code:... `while(grade!='Q'&& grade!='q')` - Did you know that `grade` may be `q`?. Using uninitialized variable is Undefined behavior

Comment: use `tolower()` so you don't have to check for both upper and lower case values.

Comment: Yes, use tolower or toupper.  You could also use a switch statement to reduce all of those chained "else if" statements.  Also, you could test `strchr('ABCDFQ', toupper(grade))` to see if the input is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to take into consideration only the first character that's entered, then don't read a single character and then base all the decisions on it. Use `std::getline()` to read an entire line into a `std::string`, and then check it for valid values.

Additionally, your existing code has undefined behavior, because `grade` is uninitialized before its first use.